# unable to connect to wireless printer

Tags: wireless, printing, broadcom, reset, peripherals

In using Ubuntu 14.04 on DELL XPS, I was unable to ping my previously setup printer that was working the day before. I found a solution but it took a lot of time. What is the  fastest way to reset the wireless connections in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: I'd say that is disable and then enable the wi-fi card with the correct keyboard shortcuts...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to discover and ping the printer from a Mac but not from the DELL XPS. It occurred to me that perhaps there was a conflict with other users in the network. I searched 'unable to ping printer at 10.0.1.2' Taking the hint from another similar question I found, I unplugged the modem, router, and printer and restarted the system components.

Ubuntu still didn't show the printer until I deleted the old connection to the printer and cold rebooted the DELL XPS laptop. The System Settings/Printers then showed the printer after I clicked on Network Printer and added the printer which now works as before.

I imagine this wasn't the fastest way but solved the problem. I decided to post this on Ubuntu Help page, in case others find similar connection problems.